# How to start a Fragment/Activity within Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

[image]

I have a button in `Fragment`. When `Button` is clicked it has to Open new `Fragment/Activity` within `Fragment`. I have written code using `Intent`,
                             `Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(getActivity(), UpdateProfile.class);
                startActivity(i);` 
but its opening in new activity like in below image.
[image]

My requirement is in Picture 1. Can someone suggest me how to do it?

**EDIT**: As suggested by rai and ADK, its working fine but new fragment overlays on old fragment. See the below image. "Change Password"(`TextView`) is New Fragment which overlays on existing fragment.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(containerViewId, newFragment)
    .addToBackStack(null) // enables back key
    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE) // if you need transition
    .commit();
```

Comment: In newFragment, I have to give  id or Classname??

Comment: @DroidLearner Neither. Pass instantiated `Fragment`. In your case, `UpdateProfile.instantiate(getActivity(), "fragment name"))`, may be?

Comment: `Fragment fg = new UpdateProfile();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
          fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fJobcard,fg );
          fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
          fragmentTransaction.commit();`
    Ya I got it.. But this new Fragment overlays on New fragment.

Comment: @DroidLearner Ah, sorry for the confusion. Either `Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), UpdateProfile.class.getName())` or `new UpdateProfile()` will work.

Comment: Thanks!! Please check my edited post. I have attached new Image. @rai

Comment: @DroidLearner So you are using static <fragment> element in your layout xml, right? I wrote "container"ViewId, which isn't a <fragment> element but a <FrameLayout>. To learn more, see the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html).

Comment: In short, you have to replace the fragment element to FrameLayout and manually inflate your first fragment in onCreate() of the parent activity.

Comment: `LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
      .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.frame, null);` Now inflated layout is in view. whaat I have to do next?

Comment: @DroidLearner Did you read the tutorial link I mentioned above? That should almost be the answer :)

Comment: Yes I did.. but you have mentioned me _"manually inflate your first fragment in onCreate() of the parent activity."_ I did. I don't know what to do next?

Comment: @DroidLearner I didn't mean `LayoutInflater#inflate` in _inflate_, but I meant that you have to do `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit()` in `Activity#onCreate()` (and replace `<fragment android:name="[firstFragmentClassName]">` to  `<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container">` in your layout xml).

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984101/replacing-fragment-didnt-work

Answer (score 1):

You should to use FragmentTransaction [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions).

Like this

```
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.yourFragment, YourFragmentWithImageClass.getInstance());
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

in your Activity

Comment: http://oi48.tinypic.com/1j3i1k.jpg check this.. I'm not getting `.getInstance();` BTW My Main class extends `Fragment` not `FragmentActivity`

Comment: Ohh sorry....define getInstance() in YourFragmentWithImageClass method returned new YourFragmentWithImageClass()

Comment: yea.. I got it.. But i have another issue.. Please check edit in this post. I updated this post with new Image.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984101/replacing-fragment-didnt-work